# how the classes should be written in a maintainable way

Tags: css, sass

I have following snippet

```
.global-oxygen-font{
    font-family: $font-oxygen;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 31px;
    letter-spacing: 0.32px;
}
```

And I am extending it whenever it is used like this

line 100. div{@extend .global-oxygen-font}

line 200.  p{@extend .global-oxygen-font}

So as you can see among different sections, I am extending the font-snippet. But during a code review I was told that put that

```
div,p{
 font-family: $font-oxygen;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 31px;
 letter-spacing: 0.32px;
}
```

on the line 100 itself. Extending global-oxygen-font would essentially copy the code those places. I was like, but div and p exists in line 100 and 200 for a reason, as they are in order of the structure of the markup. And if I make the change as suggested, it won't be good for maintenance. Whose approach is correct?

Comment: Please give constructive criticism before making my question go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Extending global-oxygen-font would essentially copy the code those places

No, that's not how `@extend` works. Instead it works by **adding** `div` and `p` to the list of selectors for `.global-oxygen-font`. (Compile it and view the result to verify this yourself.)

Therefore, if pressed I would say you are right, they are wrong. Your approach clearly isolates the rules and then assigns them to `p` and `div`, and therefore I would say it is also more maintainable.

You might want to designate `.global-oxygen-font` as a virtual class (using `%` IIRC) so no rules are generated for it (unless you want to be able to use that class explicitly).

I'm curious, though, why you would apply these rules to all `p` and `div` elements. It would seem to be better to write the class explicitly on those elements. Or, since all the properties are inheritable, it could make sense to apply them at a higher level.

Another comment:

> as they are in order of the structure of the markup

There is no particular need to order your CSS so as to match the structure of the markup.

At the end of the day, it is often not a good idea to push back against code reviewers. They may have their own point of view, which they are allowed to assert because they are more senior. For instance, they might not even like the entire idea of `@extend`, and there are legitimate reasons some people avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It would be helpful if you can explain a little more regarding the point. Would it be more maintainable or not?